# maven-jar-plugin add timestamp in Manifest but not with those dependencies jars

Tags: java, maven, manifest.mf

i know the timestamp is because i use SNAPSHOTs and there're reason for this. maven generated MANIFEST file is :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: educi
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_80
Class-Path: guice-servlet-2.0.jar reflections-0.9.10.jar javassist-3.1
 9.0-GA.jar annotations-2.0.1.jar httpclient-4.5.3.jar httpcore-4.4.6.
 jar commons-logging-1.2.jar jungle-server-core-3.6.9.alpha-SNAPSHOT.j
 ar slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar jungle-api-3.6.9.alpha-SNAPSHOT.jar jetty-cli
 ent-7.0.2.v20100331.jar jetty-http-7.0.2.v20100331.jar jetty-io-7.0.2
 .v20100331.jar jetty-util-7.0.2.v20100331.jar jungle-nativex-ptcmlb-6
 4.0.0.7-SNAPSHOT.jar jungle-nativex-wzmq-64.0.0.6-20140620.082549-4.j
 ar netty-all-4.0.45.Final.jar wup-1.1.0.jar protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar c
 ommons-codec-1.4.jar kilim-1.0.5.jar datacollector-1.8.1.jar TDBusSDK
 -0.0.7.jar netty-3.8.0.Final.jar snappy-java-1.1.0.jar fastjson-1.2.3
 8.jar jungle-nativex-uls-64.0.0.14-SNAPSHOT.jar jungle-nativex-tmem-a
 sync-64.0.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar jungle-nativex-secapi-0.0.2-64-20140107.0
 95450-4.jar jungle-nativex-l5-0.0.2-64-20140107.095453-6.jar jackson-
 core-asl-1.9.4.jar jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.4.jar jungle-jniloader-0.0.
 1-SNAPSHOT.jar guava-20.0.jar jungle-core-3.5.8.alpha-SNAPSHOT.jar di
 sruptor-3.3.4.jar log4j-api-2.3.jar log4j-core-2.3.jar log4j-slf4j-im
 pl-2.3.jar aopalliance-1.0.jar commons-io-1.4.jar commons-pool-1.6.ja
 r commons-configuration-1.6.jar commons-collections-3.2.1.jar commons
 -lang-2.4.jar commons-digester-1.8.jar commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar co
 mmons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar asm-all-4.1.jar zookeeper-3.4.5.jar ne
 tty-3.2.2.Final.jar javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar xmemcached-1.3.5.jar
 jungle-nativex-xoilib-64.0.0.7-20160506.092827-1.jar curator-framewor
 k-2.1.0-incubating.jar curator-client-2.1.0-incubating.jar joda-time-
 2.9.7.jar jungle-nativex-msgq-64.0.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar jungle-nativex-oi
 cq-0.0.3-20160525.091252-1.jar edu-info-read-pb-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar me
 ssage-sys-pb-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar junit-4.11.jar hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
 rpc-proxy-4.0.5-SNAPSHOT.jar jedis-2.9.0.jar commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar
 jungle-nativex-cmlb-64.0.0.1-20140820.093005-4.jar slf4j-log4j12-1.5.
 11.jar log4j-1.2.14.jar edu-timer-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar quartz-2.2.2.jar
  c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar timer-pb-1.0.0-20171117.013525-14.jar jungle-db-0.1
 .3-20160403.101241-1.jar mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar mybatis-3.3.
 0.jar mybatis-guice-3.7.jar guice-4.0.jar javax.inject-1.jar gson-2.3
 .1.jar HikariCP-java6-2.3.9.jar jsqlparser-0.9.3.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.2.5
Main-Class: com.tencent.eduChat.Bootstrap
```

but the jar files generated by mvn rar:rar won't come along with those timestamps .

**my question is why the actual jar file name isn't identical with the MANIFEST.MF description.**

i think that's why i can't use `-jar $path/lib/${MY_JAR_NAME}`  to launch my project , this way works `-cp .:${path}/lib/* ${MAIN_CLASS}` , but `jar` way is better , because everything including the MAIN_CLASS is described in MANIFEST.MF . Another solution is to use `<userUniqueVersions>false<useUniqueVersions>` config to force maven get rid of timestamps . but i think timestamp comes for a reason , it's not a good idea to work around it .

---

`http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.tencent.jungle</groupId>
    <artifactId>jungle-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.7.alpha-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>javasvr_edu_chat</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>javasvr_edu_user_center</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <kilim.weave.required>true</kilim.weave.required>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tencent.jungle.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jungle-panther</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tencent.jungle</groupId>
        <artifactId>jungle-server-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.9.alpha-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tencent.jungle.nativex</groupId>
        <artifactId>jungle-nativex-tmem-async</artifactId>
        <version>64.0.0.10-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.tencent.jungle.nativex</groupId>
                <artifactId>jungle-nativex-xoilib</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>20.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tencent.jungle</groupId>
        <artifactId>jungle-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.8.alpha-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>

            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tencent.jungle.nativex</groupId>
        <artifactId>jungle-nativex-msgq</artifactId>
        <version>64.0.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tencent.jungle.nativex</groupId>
        <artifactId>jungle-nativex-oicq</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tencent.edu.pb</groupId>
        <artifactId>edu-info-read-pb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tencent.edu.pb</groupId>
        <artifactId>message-sys-pb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tencent.jungle</groupId>
        <artifactId>rpc-proxy</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.tencent.jungle</groupId>
                <artifactId>jungle-server-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tencent.edu.timer</groupId>
        <artifactId>edu-timer</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tencent.jungle</groupId>
        <artifactId>jungle-db</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.tencent.eduChat.Bootstrap</mainClass>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>
                            ${project.build.directory}/lib
                        </outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`
here's my pom.xml . tks :)

Comment: Please show the full pom file...